# loop won't go through first if statement

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My code will only go through to the first if statement where it checks the value of key for headline1 etc... The first if statement works properly but it won't work with any of the following if statements when the first one isn't true. I've switched the second statement to the first where it checks for 'desc1' and then it works for that one only.

The purpose of this function is to check each key of an object and return the key when its value is over a certain length so I can add a class and show user some warning. This is in Vue JS so ads is in data and characterCheck is in computed property.

```
ads: [
  {
    headline1: '_keyword_',
    headline2: 'Online',
    headline3: 'Free',
    desc1: 'Buy online _keyword_',
    desc2: ' Vast collection of _keyword_',
    finalurl: 'www.books.com',
    path1: '',
    path2: '',
    boolean: true
  }
]

characterCheck () {
  for(var x = 0; x < this.ads.length; x++){
    if(this.ads[x]['boolean'] == true) {
      for(var key in this.ads[x]){
        var length = this.ads[x][key].replace(/_keyword_/g, this.activeKeyword).length
        if( key === 'headline1' || key === 'headline2' || key === 'headline3'){
          if(length > 30){
            return key
          }
        } else if( key == 'desc1' || key == 'desc2'){
          if(length > 90){
            return key
          }
        } else if( key == 'path1' || key == 'path2'){
          if(length > 15){
            return key
          }
        } else {
          return false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of branches here that aren't resolved. Do you know which ones are executed? Consider explicitly writing each one so you can determine exactly what path is being followed. Also consider supplying sample input and the expected result...

Comment: You're using triple equals the first time, and normal equals subsequently.  Intentional?

Comment: @tehhowch Everything works up until the if statements after setting 'var length'. It's looping through the ad that is set to true, there will be multiple ads and only one will be set to true which is why it checks that value first. The first if statement works properly where it checks for key  to be 'headline1' 'headline2' 'headline3' but when it's false and I expect key to be 'desc1' 'desc2' or any of the other keys the if statements don't evaluate. I switched up the if statements to narrow down the problem and check for key== 'desc1' or key == 'desc2' FIRST and then suddenly that  works.

Comment: I tried triple equals the first time just to see if for some reason that would do the trick. Was just getting desperate here lol @another-dave

Comment: As for what it should return, at this point I just want to return the key where the value of a key has a length is over a certain character limit, which is where the if statements kick in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your first nested `if` condition fails, the code goes to next subsequent `else-if`. For some particular value, all the `if` and `else-if` block fails and code lands on final `else` block which contains a `return` statement.

If your code reaches even once there, the entire function execution immediately stops and `false` value is returned.

Since, you wish to wait as long as you have not looped through all the values, remove the `else` part and add a simple `return` statement to the end of the for loop like this:

```
function characterCheck () {
    for(var x = 0; x < this.ads.length; x++) {
        if(this.ads[x]['boolean'] == true) {
            for(var key in this.ads[x]) {
                var length = this.ads[x][key].replace(/_keyword_/g, this.activeKeyword).length
                if( key === 'headline1' || key === 'headline2' || key === 'headline3') {
                    if(length > 30) {
                        return key
                    }
                } 
                else if( key == 'desc1' || key == 'desc2') {
                    if(length > 90) {
                        return key
                    }
                } else if( key == 'path1' || key == 'path2') {

                    if(length > 15) {
                        return key
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: You got it! Thanks! @harshalpatil